# Build-failed -- check your build output while deploying react.js app on heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, build, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a React app on heroku. I used the `https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack` buildpack but I'm getting one error on Heroku build output while deploying that:

```
/tmp/build_94536341/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js:664
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        ^
TypeError: MiniCssExtractPlugin is not a constructor
    at module.exports (/tmp/build_94536341/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js:664:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_94536341/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js:58:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-project@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-project@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.XRGUD/_logs/2022-02-11T14_01_23_303Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-project@0.1.0 heroku-postbuild: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-project@0.1.0 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.XRGUD/_logs/2022-02-11T14_01_23_320Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile React.js (create-react-app) multi app.
 !     Push failed
```

I've tried to update my `node_modules/react-scripts/web/config/webpack.config.js:664` and changed:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require(MinCssExtraPlugin).default
```

but still couldn't push `node_modules/` to GitHub because of its large size.

This is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "react-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.3.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "chart.js": "^3.7.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^4.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-leaflet": "^3.2.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "serve": "^13.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "serve -s build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
      },
      "buildpacks": [
        {
          "url": "mars/create-react-app"
        }
      ],
      "engines": {
        "node": "14.17.6"
      },
```

And this is `heroku logs`:

```
$ heroku logs --app covid19-tracke                https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/74f492ce-ac26-42da-8ace-d86bccd1f6eb/act
 »   Warning: heroku update available from       
 »   7.53.0 to 7.59.2.                           
2022-02-11T13:59:20.663970+00:00 app[api]: Releasfailed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/74f492ce-ac26-42da-8ace-d86bccd1f6eb/acte v1 created by user soniyajaiswal995@gmail.com  
2022-02-11T13:59:20.663970+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user soniyajaiswal995@gmail.com     cker/react-project (main)
2022-02-11T13:59:20.859890+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user soniyajaiswal995@gmail.com      
2022-02-11T13:59:20.859890+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user soniyajaiswal995@gmail.com  
2022-02-11T14:00:56.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build 
started by user soniyajaiswal995@gmail.com       
2022-02-11T14:01:23.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build 
failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/74f492ce-ac26-42da-8ace-d86bccd1f6eb/activity/builds/c842204e-e388-4c84-887c-d8cc1665f3fc

2022-02-11T14:47:12.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user soniyajaiswal995@gmail.com
2022-02-11T14:47:40.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/74f492ce-ac26-42da-8ace-d86bccd1f6eb/activity/builds/bfa6cebc-8775-4180-b14d-9ef96f3bfea6
```

How can I update `node_modules/` without pushing to GitHub (in `.gitignore` file)? Or maybe there is another solution?

Comment: "I'tried to push node_modules after updating"—your `node_modules/` shouldn't be tracked at all. Remove it from your repository with something like `git rm -r --cached node_modules/`, then commit and redeploy. Or maybe it is already ignored?

Comment: "I've tried to update my node_modules/react-scripts/web/config/webpack.config.js"—never modify _anything_ in `node_modules/`. That directory is owned by Yarn or NPM or whatever dependency manager you are using. Let it do its thing. Changing things in there is _not_ the solution.

Comment: See the attached duplicate, but ignore the answers telling you to modify anything in `node_modules/`. If you [upgrade to `mini-css-extract-plugin` version 2.5.1 or later](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70727935/354577) this should go away. So `yarn upgrade mini-css-extract-plugin` or `npm update mini-css-extract-plugin`.

Comment: yes, I did put node_modules in .gitignore file but then this error came up on heroku build output that "TypeError: MiniCssExtractPlugin is not a constructor" so I tried to change and push node_modules in my repo but could'nt solve this issue.

Comment: Please don't push `node_modules/`. You'll want to remove it from your project: `git rm -r --cached node_modules/ && git commit -m "Untrack node_modules/"`.